# How to enable the tethering programatically in Android 4.0 and 3.0

Tags: android, usb, tethering

I am developing an android application(for Version 4.0) which needs of using the USB tethering. But I could not able to switch on the tethering programatically. Please share your ideas if anyone have solution for this. Thanks.